# Extracting input from html with POST

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, post

I am trying to read in input(string from a file, 2 ints from text fields) from html in Google App Engine and put them into a function. The input section is:

```
self.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' \
                     % os.environ['PATH_INFO'])
        self.write('<input type="file" name="pdf_file" />')
        self.write('<input type="text" name="generations" />')
        self.write('<input type="text" name="legnthOfDay" />')
        self.write('<input type="submit" value="Submit" />')
```

The output part will hopefully be:

```
 def post(self):
        """Convert, parse and print text from converted PDF."""
        text = self.request.POST['pdf_file'].file.read()
        lengthOfDay = int(text=self.request.POST['lengthOfDay'])
        generations = int(text=self.request.POST['generations'])
        sim = Simulation(text, generations, lengthOfDay
```

The text line of output, taken from an example online, works, but only if there was a file, how can I catch it and continue if there was no file given?
The next two lines I wrote are a problem. I don't actually know what request.POST[...] returns, so what does it give me and how can I extract the ints from it?

Comment: You should check the state/value of file before attempting to read.

Comment: How do I do that, I'm not sure what POST['pdf_file'] returns so I don't know how .file deals with it.

Comment: You could do some basic debugging.  You haven't included the error when there is no file. That will give you a lot of clues 

 You haven't  said what framework your using, so I am going to assume it's webapp2.     If so then do some reading on how to handle files http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html  See the section marked files.  
 But normally you can just use `if`  as in `if self.request.POST['pdf_file'].file:`

Comment: Well that makes a lot of sense. But again is POST just a dictionary? If so then 'pdf_file' is a key that points to something, I guess a string, and this is the same for lengthOfDay and generations.

Comment: Did you read the doc I provided the link to. POST is something that looks like a dictionary (so treat it as one).   If your using webapp2 then file with be an instance of cgi.FieldStorage.  You should read docs.

Comment: Forget all I said, you're right I had a stupid typo that was blocking everything. Move your comments to the answer and I'll give you the check. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=You haven't included the error when there is no file.

That will give you a lot of clues You haven't said what framework your using, so I am going to assume it's webapp2.

If so then do some reading on how to handle files 
http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html  See the section marked files.

Normally you can just use if as in

```
if self.request.POST['pdf_file'].file: 
    # do something"
```